# clone() dose not bind event / plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clone

I have parallax attached to same div which I clone but after I clone parallax stops working for cloned elements.
Check my example : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYOrEO

My Code:
Html :

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="clone">Clone</a>
</div>
<section class="content">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center bg-faded my-5" style="background: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/abstract/1') no-repeat center;" data-paroller-factor="0.5">
    <h1 class="heading-1 py-5 text-white">Hello Parallax!</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).paroller();
$(function(){
  $('.clone').on('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
    $(".jumbotron").clone().appendTo(".content");
  });
});
```

Example : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYOrEO

Thanx in advance

Comment: you may want to [read some documentation](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) about the clone function to see where you went wrong - though, perhaps the problem is that "paroller" doesn't work that way

Comment: any help will be appreciated thanx, been working on it and couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: according to the documentation, if you want events cloned you need to say `.clone(true)` - however, that seems to make no difference to paroller

Comment: yes thats what, I even tried that but nothing helped with it.

Comment: Paroller is probably doing more than just binding event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before and it can be done. It was a problem with CSS taking effect when page laods and not when you clone.

If I remembered right to fix it you need to create an object of the cloned div similar to this example:

```
// will be different for you!! but might set you on the right direction
var divToClone = document.getElementsByID("#cloneMe");
var clone = divToClone.cloneNode(true);
var element = clone.getElementsByTagName("h1");
```

Now with my var Element I can add attributes and style again like this

```
//Nothing to do with parallax here but look at you CSS and fill it in again like below
element.innerHTML = "Whatever you want or need"; 
element.style['background']= "url(/iwa/images/16x16/randomExample.png) no-repeat, fixed";
element.style['background-position']='center right';
element.style['border']='none';
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanx for your answer appreciate it. 
Can this be done without adding inline css? Here i need to output clean div with predefined css that I have?

Comment: It was over a year ago I had this problem so I can't remember exactly but I can take a look at my old projects in a bit when I get a chance to see if I can dig it up

Comment: Thank you @Super Hans that will help me.

Comment: Try using Deep Clone Vicky something like this  $('your-selector').clone(true, true)

Comment: I have tried this as well to deep clone but this is also not working for me.

Comment: Sorry I never got back to you. Did you manage to solve your problem?